# Is there a way to redirect a request from API server to a different service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ingress

I have read about ingress/ingress controller etc. But what I really want is to redirect request to API server to a new service. Some sort of webhook implementation. Say I have to request a resource creation, can that go through some custom validation and then proceed with creation.